# Can I share boost::asio::tcp::socket object between 2 threads that perform read and write

Tags: boost-asio

I have two threads, one sending and another receiving data via TCP socket. 
I use `boost::asio::read()` and `boost::asio::write()` for reading and writing. My question is do I have to guard the access to socket object during read and write operation?

The other case would be what if I have two threads both writing using the same socket object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The socket is not thread safe when shared between two or more threads. For more information look at the Boost.Asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket.html).