# boost.asio composed operation run in strand

Tags: boost-asio

The code:

In thread 1:

```
boost::async_read(socket, buffer, strand.wrap(read_handler));
```

In thread 2:

```
strand.post([](){socket.async_write_some(buffer, strand.wrap(write_handler))});
```

It is clear that *read_handler*, *async_write_some*, *write_handler* protected by strand, they will not concurrent. However, async_read is an composed operation, it will call zero or more times to async_read_some, those async_read_some also need protect by strand or else they might concurrent with async_write_some in thread 2.

But from the code, strand only wrap *read_handler*, how asio make all intermediate operations(async_read_some) also wrapped by the strand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, [`asio_handler_invoke`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html) enables one to customize the invocation of handlers in the context of a different handler.  In this case, the object returned from [`strand.wrap()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html) has a custom `asio_handler_invoke` strategy associated with it that will dispatch handlers into the strand that wrapped the initial handler.  Conceptually, it is as follows:

```cpp
template <typename Handler>
struct strand_handler
{
  void operator()();
  Handler handler_;
  boost::asio::strand dispatcher_;
};

// Customize invocation of Function within context of custom_handler.
template <typename Function>
void asio_handler_invoke(Function function, strand_handler* context)
{
  context->dispatcher_.dispatch(function);
}

strand_handler wrapped_completion_handler = strand.wrap(completion_handler);
using boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke;
asio_handler_invoke(intermediate_handler, &wrapped_completion_handler);
```

The custom `asio_handler_invoke` hook is located via [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).  This detail is documented in the [Handler requirement](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html):

> Causes the function object `f` to be executed as if by calling `f()`.
>
> The `asio_handler_invoke()` function is located using argument-dependent lookup. The function `boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke()` serves as a default if no user-supplied function is available.

For more details on `asio_handler_invoke`, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32892581/1053968) answer.

---

Be aware that an *operation* may be attempted within the initiating function.  The documentation is specific that intermediate *handlers* will be invoked within the same context as the final completion handler.  Therefore, given:

```cpp
assert(strand.running_in_this_thread());
boost::async_read(socket, buffer, strand.wrap(read_handler));
```

the `boost::async_read` itself must be invoked within the context of `strand` to be thread-safe.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36023041/1053968) answer for more details on thread-safety and strands.